# What to do with an unsettled Git after moving workspace?

Tags: git

I am new to Git & started to use it after I watched a video on YouTube for newcomers. The workspace I was using was on the D: drive on the Windows notebook, and I moved it to another location on OneDrive. Then, I zipped the project folder and unzipped the last zip file that I created on the D: drive. I got some errors (similar to those below) and removed this directory, unzipping the moved project file. This unsettled Git.

In the new directory, I get the following message after the status command:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   AstroCoordinates (modified content, untracked content)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .metadata/
  
  no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What I need is

1. either some touches that make Git clear that the only project called *AstroCoordinates* is to be added without any "inappropriate" messages, or, as I am the only developer of the project, to
2. "reset" git so that it starts from the "beginning", i.e. to make changes to the workspace such that Git does not "understand" that it was used in this directory.

What I cannot accept is that project files are deleted. My `.gitignore` file says to ignore `/bin` and `.metadata` only.

Comment: Git isn't unsettled. It's telling you that the tracked file `AstroCoordinates` has been modified, and the untracked file (or folder) `.metadata/` has been added. It says nothing about any other files.

Comment: What can I do to get rid of these messages then? I want that Git works "as before" without any untracked files/folders. A `git add .` does not change anything. Which set of commands am I supposed to enter to get rid of this problem, to make files in modified `AstroCoordinates` to be staged for commit again?

Comment: Do you want to keep the changes made to `AstroCoordinates`? If so, you'll need to commit them. Beware, `git add .` adds both `.metadata/` and `AstroCoordinates` (which I doubt you want) --- I encourage you to learn the basics of git https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-the-basics-of-git-in-under-10-minutes-da548267cc91/

Comment: By the way: You must never keep a Git repository on a OneDrive volume.

Comment: Why not, matt? Having the repository on OneDrive, the main reason to introduce Git given by Linus Torvalds is undone: the Internet was not omnipresent in 2005, but it *is* omnipresent in the Western world today. There is no need to have any workspace files locally nowadays, isn't it?

Comment: Git doesn't work well with onedrive, dropbox, etc. There's no reason to put it in there anyway since it is a _distributed version control system_

Comment: OK, that's an argument! AND IT SOLVED MY PROBLEM, as I returned to the D: drive, where everything is as it should be. THANK YOU!

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

ekrem@LAPTOP-ZEKAI-SABAN MINGW64 /d/Users/ekrem/eclipse/workspace/AstroCoordinates (master)
$

Comment: I'll give it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I moved it to another location on OneDrive

That's the problem. Git doesn't work correctly when you put a repository / working tree on a shared volume of this sort (OneDrive, DropBox, etc.), for the very reason you are experiencing: the shared volume mechanism itself makes alterations to the working tree, and Git picks up on those and thinks that *you* made those alterations.

But in any case, as has been pointed out in a comment, there is no *need* to keep the repository on a shared volume, because Git is *already* a distributed system by its very nature.